# Is there an 'inverse' to the tilde function for plotting in R

Tags: r, plot, violin-plot

If the starting data is:

```
[![df = data.frame(AAA=rnorm(1000,1,1),
                BBB=sample(LETTERS,1000,replace=TRUE))
df = droplevels(df\[df$BBB %in% unique(df$BBB)\[1:5\] == TRUE,\])][1]][1] # Not sure how to do this less dumb...
# Just random number of values to 5 random letters
```

and in this case, I'm using package vioplot to plot:

```
vioplot(AAA~BBB, data = df, side = "right")
```

I would like to then plot on "side = left" all of the data *not* selected for each x-axis entry
So if it was plotting on the right the values for df$BBB == "A", I would want it to plot on the left, the  !(df$BBB == "A"). And so on for each letter.

Also just as a note, the number of x-axis levels is undefined. Ideally, I'd like to not install any packages.

My goal was to highlight, if present, the difference between sampled population vs remaining population using a split violin plot.

Thanks for any help

My workaround at the moment is (I'm still really clumsy with R):

```
Plotting_Vios_T <- function(input_Data) {
  library(vioplot)
  vioplot(AAA~BBB, data = input_Data, side = "right")
  x = list()
  y = list()
  for(idx_class in 1:length(unique(input_Data$BBB))) {
    y_t <- input_Data[!(input_Data$BBB == unique(input_Data$BBB)[idx_class]),"AAA"]
    x_t <- rep(unique(input_Data$BBB)[idx_class], length(y_t))

    x <- c(x,x_t)
    y <- c(y,y_t)
    }
  df <- data.frame(x = as.character(x), y = as.numeric(y))
  vioplot(y~x, data = df, side = "left", add = TRUE)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your goal is a good idea for comparison purposes!

However, it doesn't seem the `violoplot()` function implements that option --based on its documentation page. So, your approach should be the way to go considering that, for each group, the set of records satisfying the complement condition (i.e. all but the records in the group) is *different*. Which means that you need one different object (one per group) to store that information, which is precisely what you do.

Nevertheless, following is a piece of code that makes the following improvements to your code:

- it **reduces memory** (as it creates the data for each complement group and adds the boxplot to the plot *rightaway* --without storing it in a data frame containing the records for *all* the complement groups)
- it **reduces execution time** (as it computes the unique `BBB` values only once --before the `for` loop using `table()`)
- it **is more readable** :)

(Note that I don't use the `violoplot()` function because I don't have the `vioplot` package installed, I simply use the `boxplot()` function but you should be able to extend this to your violin plots)

### The test data to plot

I changed the example data to make a plot that better conveys what we are after, as follows:

- I've reduced the number of groups (values of `BBB`) just to the first 3 letters
- For each group I create a normal distribution whose mean is the ordinal value of the letter (i.e. 1, 2 or 3) (this makes the distribution of the numeric variable `AAA` in each group be distinguishable)

-

```
# The data to plot
set.seed(117)
groups = LETTERS[1:3]
df = data.frame(BBB=sample(groups,1000,replace=TRUE))
df_sp = split(df, df$BBB)
df_sp = lapply(df_sp, transform, AAA = rnorm(length(BBB), mean=as.numeric(BBB), sd=0.2))
df = unsplit(df_sp, df$BBB)
head(df)  

  BBB       AAA
1   C 2.7884212
2   A 0.7924213
3   B 2.0032205
4   B 2.2402493
5   C 3.0513685
6   A 1.2553530
```

### The example graph

First we generate the boxplots by group (your "right" violin plot) and then we add the boxplots of the complement of each group (your "left" violin plot).

```
# Groups to plot
groups = names(table(df$BBB))

# Reduce margins to make plot bigger
op = par(mar=c(5.1,4.1,0.1,0.1))

# Generate the boxplots by group (this would be your "right" violin plots)
boxplot(AAA ~ BBB, data=df, at=(1:length(groups)), boxwex=0.2)

# Add the distribution of the complement (this would be your "left" violin plots)
grp_idx = 0   # This variable is used to define the X location to add the boxplot to.
              # You would also need it in the violoplot() function for the 'at=' parameter
for (grp in groups) {
  grp_idx = grp_idx + 1

  # Complement data to plot for the group
  df_complement = df[ df$BBB!=grp, ]
  df_complement$BBB = grp

  # The 'at' parameter indicates the correct X location to add the boxplot to
  # which is shifted a little bit (by +0.2) to avoid overlap with the boxplot of the group
  boxplot(AAA ~ BBB, data=df_complement, col="red", add=TRUE, at=grp_idx+0.2, boxwex=0.2)
}

# Restore margins
par(op)
```

Note that we do *not* need to pre-calculate the Y-axis range to make every `add`ed boxplot fit in the base boxplots by group graph, because that original boxplot already covers ALL the Y-axis range present in the data --as it plots ALL the data.

The above code produces:

[image: Boxplots by group and their complements]

So your job would be to adapt the above code to use the `violoplot()` function.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know about the "at" parameter, seems useful. (nor that you could index "LETTERS"...)

Comment: You are welcome. Yes, `LETTERS` is an array and therefore you can subset it with the `[` operator, as for any array, vector, matrix, data frame, ...